# Do entire IC labels need to match? ULN2803A replacement

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, surface-mount, uln2803

I burned out an IC on my OmniLogic pool controller and am looking to try to replace it. I've never attempted repairs with ICs before, and don't know much about them. The chip is a TI 1CZRL34 ULN2803A G4 (picture included below). Would any ULN2803A IC work, such as [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/umw/ULN2803A/16705954) one [(datasheet)](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/UTD%20Semi%20PDFs/ULN2803.pdf)? I believe [this](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.net/datasheet-pdf/view/177072/TI/ULN2803A.html) is the datasheet for the original part, for reference.

[image: Picture of IC]

Comment: Compare the datasheets. The ULN2803 is a very old chip, so it's likely a number of manufacturers make compatible equivalents. The original manufacturer may not even make it anymore; it's pretty obsolete technology.

Comment: As long as it's the same package type as the original, you should be fine. Sometimes the extra part designations specify temperature range or other specs, but it could also be as simple as a date-of-manufacture code (can't tell from the datasheet). Just take care desoldering. Instead of trying to desolder the whole row of leads, I prefer to clip them all, remove the body, then desolder the remnants one by one.

Comment: @Hearth I'm not familiar with logic diagrams except from college physics, but with some Googling they appear to be the same.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt Interesting, thank you for your insight and for the tip about clipping the leads and then desoldering the remnants!

Comment: @MarkLeavitt I'm partial to using a dental probe to bend up the leads on the part being desoldered as you hold the iron to each one, myself. Of course, if you have access to a hot air station (and you can get a half-decent cheap one for like $100~$150), that makes desoldering surface-mount stuff so much easier.

Comment: How do you know that IC is burnt and needs replacing? Is that covered with lacquer or conformal coating of some sort for outdoor use?

Comment: @Justme This is a picture of the same chip on a different board.

Comment: OK - how did you burn it? Since chips don't burn up themselves, there was a fault somewhere in the circuit. Just making sure that the fault is now fixed, so that it does not burn the new chip again?

Comment: @Justme I was measuring the voltage on the relay header to determine how to connect it and shorted across the pins – won't make that mistake again!